# Loading JS and CSS scripts from a secondary source

Tags: javascript, html

How do I load javascript or css files from another source should the primary source be unavailable? I was thinking of something like

```
   <script src="https://me.domain.com/scripts/me_script.min.js" fallback-src="https://me2.domain.com/scripts/me_script.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I don't think there's a built-in way. You can use an `onerror` attribute to run a function that loads the alternate source.

Comment: you load both the scripts, the fallback being first

Comment: @TilakMaddy but won't that result to the script being loaded twice?

Comment: @Barmar i'll look into it

Answer (score 0):

you can simply load any css file inside another like the following

```
@import "style_2.css"
```

inside the `style_1` which you linked to html like the following

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style_1.css">
```

and you can do it the javascript like the following

```
let script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = 'custom_2.js';
document.body.append(script);
```

then attach the first to the dom

```
<script src="custom_1.js"></script>
```

Comment: I want to load 1 file from two different sources. not 2 different files from 1 source

Comment: OK that was my attempt but I don't know if that could be possible